# Send data from Contact Form 7 to Infusionsoft

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, infusionsoft

I have a Wordpress website that has a Contact Form 7 web form on it.

I use the following code for the form:

```
<div class="h-form-in">
      [text* infusionsoft-FirstName class:form-control placeholder "First Name*"]
</div>
<div class="h-form-in">
      [email* infusionsoft-Email class:form-control placeholder "Email*"]
</div>
<div class="h-form-in">
      [tel* infusionsoft-Phone1 class:form-control placeholder "Mobile*"]
</div>
<div class="h-form-in">
      [select* option-state class:form-control "State*" "New South Wales" "Queensland" "South Australia" "Tasmania" "Victoria" "Western Australia"]
</div>
<div class="h-form-in text-center">
      [submit class:btn class:btn-sub "Submit"]
</div>
```

My InfusionSoft App Name and InfusionSoft API Key are correct and have been saved in Wordpress correctly.

When submitted the data is sent to the specified email address correctly but the data is not passed to Infusionsoft.

Please can someone suggest a fix or advise why this might not be working?

Comment: are you using any plugin to send data on InfusionSoft  ?

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, I use this plugin from Wordpress - https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-infusionsoft-add-on/ - which works with the Contact Form 7 plugin. I do not use any plugin within Infusionsoft.

Comment: the plugin you are using in not updated for 2 years. i think it may be competibility issue

Comment: I can solve the problem for you. add me on your skype rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Rajkumar, I have added you

Comment: Unfortunately Rajkumar cannot fix this issue, can anyone else help?

Comment: Quick question for you - why you're using contact form 7 if you want to add records in infusionsoft. You can direct use infusionsoft's web form and embed the code on your website it's pretty simple and easy to use.

Comment: I have used Infusionsofts web form and it is very clunky and limited.

Answer (score 0):

Infusionsoft have changed their syntax and I have found that the following works:

```
inf_field_Phone1
```

This would be used for the mobile number and any field in your form would just need the Infusionsoft ID at the end e.g. inf_field_**xxxxx**